# Using TypeScript's .Partial to make Class fields optional

Tags: typescript

Imagine a class defined as below:

```
class MyClass {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
  constructor(arg1: string, arg2: string) {
    this.key1 = arg1;
    this.key2 = arg2;
  }
  point() {
    console.log(this.key1);
  }
}
```

I want to initiate an instance of this class without immediately providing the arguments:

```
const instance = new MyClass();
```

Is is possible to use the `.Partial` utility type to achieve this?
(PS. I do not want to add "undefined" to the class types as a workaround)

Comment: Since `MyClass` is a constructor value and not just a type, you'd have to actually write a value transformer and just a type function like `Partial`.  As an example though the code here isn't really useful; your `MyClass` instance has no defined properties, so it's hard to say what you'd want to transform it  *to*.  What happens in the constructor? What happens in the rest of the class?  Let's say your class were `class Foo { x: string; constructor(x: string) { this.x = x } bar() { this.x.toUpperCase() } };`.  What would you want `PartialFoo` to be?

Comment: (see prev comment).  Or maybe I'm overthinking this and you just want [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAPd8N)? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to clarify what specifically you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jcalz, thank you for your response. I edited the code to be more clear.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't help me. Your new code [has errors](https://tsplay.dev/m3o3Em) that you're not asking about. Can you fix those so as not to distract from the problem?  Additionally, could you please answer my question about the `Foo` example?  Note that any automatic transformation will most likely produce something where `new PartialFoo().bar()` explodes at runtime, unless you can explain exactly what rules we should follow when switching from something with required args/props to something with optional ones.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for being patient with me. The use case is: I am using this class as a model in my node server. When I instantiate an instance of this model in my controller, I want to feed in validated data piece by piece upon receiving it from the user. That is why I want to initiate it without any initial values: arg1 comes, then arg2, etc. I have about 20 args in my actual server code. The <foo> part is the database query function because all arguments are already validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dick-larsson, thank you for the hint, I know I mentioned that I prefer not to assign undefined to the types but it seems like there is no other way around, except assigning defaults values as you mentioned or the overloads, so I am doing it the way shown below. I am not sure how to implement the `.Partial` in the shorthand format (if someone could kindly let me know if there is a way) but the code below works too:

```
class MyClass {
  
  constructor(
    public key1?: string,
    public key2?: string
  ) {
   
  }

  point() {
    console.log(this.key1);
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();  // Works
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions...

```
class MyClass {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<MyClass>) {
    this.key1 = data?.key1 ?? 'default1';
    this.key2 = data?.key2 ?? 'default2';
  }

  point() {
    console.log(this.key1);
  }
}

const instance = new MyClass();  // Works
```

or overloads.

```
class MyClass {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;

  // Constructor overloads
  constructor();
  constructor(arg1: string, arg2: string);

  // Constructor implementation
  constructor(arg1?: string, arg2?: string) {
    if (arg1 !== undefined && arg2 !== undefined) {
      this.key1 = arg1;
      this.key2 = arg2;
    } else {
      this.key1 = 'default1';
      this.key2 = 'default2';
    }
  }

  point() {
    console.log(this.key1);
  }
}

const instance1 = new MyClass(); 
const instance2 = new MyClass('test1', 'test2');
```